# How to use Dart http_server:VirtualDirectory

Tags: dart, dart-io

I have been using the `dart:route` api for serving static files but I noticed that there is a core library called `http_server` that contains helper classes and functions for `dart:io` `HttpServer`.

Of particular interest to me is the class `VirtualDirectory` which, according to the docs, takes a String Object for the static content of directory and then you call the method `serve()`

```dart
var virtualDirectory = new VirtualDirectory('/var/www/');
virtualDirectory.serve(new HttpServer('0.0.0.0', 8080));
```

This doesn't work as there is no constructor for HttpServer - at least not in current versions.

```dart
virtualDirectory.serve(HttpServer.bind('0.0.0.0', 8080));
```

Which is how I have been instantiating a server also fails since `virtualDirectory.serve()` doesn't take a `Future<HttpServer>` and finally:

```dart
virtualDirectory.serve(HttpServer.bind('0.0.0.0', 8080).asStream());
```

also fails with
*The argument type 'Stream' cannot be assigned to the parameter type 
 'Stream'*

So how do I connect a VirtualDirectory to a Server?  There are no examples that I can find online and the VirtualDirectory source code does not make it clear.  I would RTFM if I could FTFM.  Links are fine as answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `VirtualDirectory` can work from inside the Future returned by `HttpServer.bind`.  You can create a static file web server by using the following five lines of code:

```dart
HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 8888).then((HttpServer server) {
    VirtualDirectory vd = new VirtualDirectory('../web/');
    vd.jailRoot = false;
    vd.serve(server);
});
```

You can make it more sophisticated by parsing the URI and pulling out service requests prior to serving out files.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http_server/http_server.dart';

main() {

  handleService(HttpRequest request) {
    print('New service request');
    request.response.write('[{"field":"value"}]');
    request.response.close();
  };

  HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 8888).then((HttpServer server) {
    VirtualDirectory vd = new VirtualDirectory('../web/');
    vd.jailRoot = false;
    server.listen((request) { 
      print("request.uri.path: " + request.uri.path);
      if (request.uri.path == '/services') {
        handleService(request);
      } else {
        print('File request');
        vd.serveRequest(request);
      } 
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: sadly, the HttpServer package is [discontinued](https://pub.dev/packages/http_server)