# How can I use the http_server package to serve several virtual web apps in Dart?

Tags: dart, virtualhost

In Dart language, the http_server package allows to implement virtual hosts.

```dart
import 'package:http_server/http_server.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {

   HttpServer.bind('localhost', 8080).then((server) {
        var virtualServer = new VirtualHost(server);
          virtualServer.addHost('domain1.com').listen(
             (HttpRequest request) {
                //  what should I do now?
             }
   });

}
```

1. How can I serve a web site in a subdirectory below /web/ using the http_server package?
2. Is it best to place the web sites below the usual "web" directory?

Comment: for 2) you may take a look at [How to organize mixed HTTP server + web client Dart project files?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http_server/http_server.dart';

void main() {
  HttpServer.bind('localhost', 8080).then((server) {
    final virtualServer = new VirtualHost(server);
    final domain1Stream = virtualServer.addHost('domain1.com');
    new VirtualDirectory('/var/www/domain1').serve(domain1Stream);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexandre! The following complements your answer, i.e., serving both static and dynamic resources: [How to use Dart http_server:VirtualDirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295603/how-to-use-dart-http-servervirtualdirectory/20320506#20320506)

Comment: And how we can combine this with Router ?

Comment: Yes it's possible. See https://github.com/ggirou/risk/blob/master/bin/main.dart#L20-L43

Comment: I would say combine with VirtualServer

Comment: You can use `router.defaultStream.listen(vDir.serveRequest)`.

Comment: If you don't see what I mean feel free to ask a new SO question.

Comment: My problem is not to server a static file directory. By example, I would use ws.mydomain.com for serve websocket.

Comment: `virtualServer.addHost('ws.mydomain.com').listen(WebSocketTransformer.upgrade).then((ws) => ...)` ?