# How to host HTTP Server on directory using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and I am trying to build an Android application that requires me to host a HTTP Server on a certain directory of the Android filesystem which would allow me to host the files in the directory on the HTTP server, similar to how Python3's `http.server` works. I have looked through the HttpServer class but I can't seem to find anything that satisfies what I need.

Comment: @pskink sorry, updated the question

Comment: @pskink sorry I misread your comment. I'm trying to go for an app that allows the user to choose the directory to host using some sort of list and activate the server using a button

Comment: @pskink I'm not asking for the whole app. I'm just trying to give you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm just looking for pointers of how I can write the app because I'm new to flutter.

Comment: `host a HTTP Server on a certain directory `. What do you mean? Indicating the server its `document root`?

Comment: @blackapps yes. the directory will serve as the HTTP server root

Comment: Have you got the server working? If yes then from wich directory does it serve now? By default?

Comment: You can use VirtualDirectory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20320506